# Matrix and graph theory

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

I have a question. I'm trying to find whether there is a connection between graphs and matrix.
I was given the next question:
$m$ is a square matrix that represents a graph that each entry has either a '0' or 
a '1'

-
if an entry $i,j$ has a '0' in it, it means that node number $j$ is not connected to node number $i$.

if an entry $i,j$ has a '1' in it, it means that node number $j$ is connected to node number $i$.

(the diagonal's entries contain '1's)

I was asked to find a method that determines whether there is a path between two given nodes $i$ and $j$.
I noticed that if I power the matrix then the entry $i,j$ doesn't equal to '0'. Does it always work like this? Is there a different way of solving this problem?

**This is a question I was asked to program, therefore I've heard of recursive solutions..but I'm trying to find a different answer

Comment: +1 for noticing that powers of the adjacency matrix provide useful information. @MishaLavrov provides alternative methods in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true that if you take the $k^{\text{th}}$ power of this matrix (the [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) of your graph), then its $(i,j)$ entry counts the number of paths of length $k$ from node number $i$ to node number $j$.

This is not an efficient method of testing if $(i,j)$ is connected by a path of any length, because you will have to do many matrix multiplications before you're sure. It's slightly improved by computing $(A+I)^k$ (where $A$ is your adjacency matrix); now the $(i,j)$ entry is $0$ if there are no paths from node $i$ to node $j$ of length $k$ or less, so $(A+I)^{n-1}$ is enough to test if there are any such paths. (And you can compute $(A+I)^{n-1}$ by repeated squaring, without having to compute all the powers in between.)

Better yet is to do a spectral analysis of the Laplacian. The [Laplacian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) $L$ has $L_{ij} = -1$ if there is an edge from node $i$ to node $j$ and $0$ otherwise; also, $L_{ii}$ is the degree of node $i$. This makes all row sums $0$, so $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue of $L$. In fact, if you let $C$ be a connected component of your graph, and let $v$ be its indicator vector ($v_i = 1$ if $i \in C$, and $0$ otherwise) then $Lv = 0$.

So you can find the number of components by just finding the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ (in other words, the dimension of the null space of $L$) and find the components themselves by finding the right eigenbasis: all eigenvectors will be constant on each component, so this is not too hard.

But a simple breadth-first search is better than all of these in general. *Maybe* you can do better by taking the matrix approach if you want to know the answer for all pairs of nodes $i$ and $j$ at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much Misha for the answer! But what do you mean by a simple breadth-first search?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124626/finding-connected-components-of-adjacency-matrix-graph.